# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Getting "No Such Session" exception while accessing the below method in selenium. I know there are lot of same questions with different answers online but none seems to be worked out in my case. Any assistance?

Chrome Driver Version:- 2.38
Chrome version:-66.0.3359.117

Exception message is:-

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'XXYYXX', ip: 'XXYYXX', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa876..., userDataDir: C:\Users\XXYYXX\AppData\L...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 66.0.3359.117, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 6db82d5d19891c00f783fd9b7cebd234
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/p}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:346)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:425)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElements(By.java:356)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:895)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:248)
    at UserInterfaceTesting.LoginValidator.validation(LoginValidator.java:31)
    at HybridFrameWork.test1.validation_of_server_response_at_something_page(test1.java:41)
    at ?.And Validation of server response at "Login" Page(Userlogin.feature:14)
```

My Program:-

```
 else if (CommonObjRepository.getMessage().contentEquals("Login")) {


// This is where exception is being thrown //
            String Message = wait
                    .until(ExpectedConditions
                            .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/p")))
                    .getText();

            assertEquals(ReadProperties.GetConstant("XXTTX"), Message);
            CommonObjRepository.getLog().info("***** XXXYYYZZZ *****");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
```

...implies that the *chromedriver=2.38* wasn't able to initiate an active session with the WebClient i.e *Chrome* browser.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- Though you are using latest *Selenium Client* version **3.11.0**, *Chrome Driver* version *2.38* and *Chrome* version *v66.0*.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_144** which is pretty **ancient**.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [JDK 8u241](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.